# How to make API request in a Shopify private APP

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

So I'm developing a private app in Shopify using node.js and react, so far it's just a form that submits new products to the store, pretty simple, the thing that I have realized is that the Admin API from Shopify won't let me make request as a private app, or so thats what I understand from it, apparently the solution has to do with setting up a back-end server, which I'm at a loss because I quickstarted the app with the Shopify CLI and sets up a ngrok tunnel server for you, I'm unsure if I would need to set up another one or what to do next.
its scaffolded with this process: https://shopify.dev/apps/getting-started/create

This article describes the perfect solution but they don't go into details about it so that's why I'm comming here:https://metafieldsmanager.thebestagency.com/articles/how-to-build-a-private-app

Code:

```
AddProductForm.js

let headers = {'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'access token',
'host': 'store-example.myshopify.com', 
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}

let baseUrl = 'https://store-example.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-07/'
```

Right now I'm just attempting a simple fetch request.

```
let handleSubmit = () => {  
        let toAdd = {
            product:{
                title: title,
                body_html: bodyHtml,
                vendor: vendor,
            }

        }
        console.log(baseUrl + 'products.json')
        fetch(baseUrl + 'products.json', {  
            headers:  headers
        }).then(res=>console.log(res))
```

I've omitted the rest of the code to keep it simple but its pretty much basic JSX and form handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of dealing with Shopify apps, you DO need another server that has some https configuration or tunnel it with `Ngrok`, that server needs to call Shopify api instead of your front-end and then the app that the Shopify CLI scaffolds for you has to call that server.